# VisualSVN over the internet Using MyEclipse access issue

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, visualsvn-server, myeclipse

I have installed visual svn on windows 2008 R2 64 bit machine.I have create repositories on the server set up all the groups correctly and assigns correct permissions to them. it works perfectly on locally.

when you try following parameters in your browser (any) you will successfully logged in to the repositories doing commit an update as well.

```
URL https://124.191.120.88:8443/svn/ 

        or

URL https://190dev.no-ip.org:8443/svn/

user name : dummy
password  : dummy123
```

it means all is well over the internet as well.

when i try above url in MyEclipse to check oyut project from svn with right credentials 
it gives me following error

if is use thishttps://124.191.120.88:8443/svn/ as a url  it gives me

```
Repository has been moved
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://124.191.120.88:8443/'; please relocate
```

if i use this https://190dev.no-ip.org:8443/svn/ as a url it first aske me about some certificate

**Error validating server certificate for https://190dev.no-ip.org:8443:
 - Unknown certificate issuer
   Fingerprint: 4f:11:c6:8a:51:3a:f6:13:b7:7a:30:d3:d5:2c:9a:2e:56:d5:23:11
   Distinguished name: 190DEV
 - Hostname mismatch (190DEV)**

i validate it and then it gives me the same error as in previous case.

My Configuration

### Visual SVN Server

Version 2.5.8

### Subversion

1.7.8

### Apache

2.2.22

### MyEclipse

8.6.1

### Eclipse

3.5.1

### Subversion Client installed in MyEclipse

Subversion Client Adapter (Required)    1.6.12  org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group

### My Os

Microsoft win xp (i think 32 bit)

### Server OS

Windows Server 2008 R2 Servcie Pack 1 64 bit

i want to checkout project from repository within MyEclipse , but any how i can not succeed.

please help me solve this issue.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: Just check that you're using the same case for "svn" all the way through.  Whilst windows doesn't care about case, unix does, and I know this has caused problems for me in the past when I've accessed it using incorrect case.

Comment: @Peter yes i have used the correct case for sure.

Comment: Hmmm I currently use visual svn with eclipse and haven't seen this kind of thing before.  I haven't used MyEclipse though... is it expecting the repository name, not just the root svn directory?  ie: "https://xxxx:8443/svn/project"

Comment: i used your suggestion with project name i am able to check out the project but when i made commit i am getting following error Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Illegal repository URL '' and eclipse log org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Illegal repository URL ''

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Illegal repository URL ''

Comment: Glad you're making progress but this error sounds awful too! Can you try updating to the latest version of subclipse within MyEclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to any browser, which can have access to SVNParentPath and list nested repositories, none of Subversion clients **now** can do it (before future SVN 1.8, where it's at least announced).

You **must** to access repository URL (which you have created already, yes?) `https://190dev.no-ip.org:8443/svn/<REPONAME>`.

Test you config with "lightweight tester" (CLI SVN-client): `svn ls <URL>` - no erors and some output means "all OK", errors will be printed as is

Example from my http-only VisualSVN-server for both paths (inside repo and in SVNParentPath)

```
> svn ls http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/
Redirecting to URL 'http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088':
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088'
svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088)

> svn ls http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

Additional (only *possible*) problem for "Repository has been moved" problem after using correct URL may be some configuration settings

1. I always use trailing slash in SVN-URL (where it's applicable)
2. In Apache config for svn location always use trailing slash also: `<Location /svn/>`
3. SVNParentPath trailslashed too: `SVNParentPath "Path/To/Parent/"`